# Ubuntu 18.04. - Desktop icons are missing in flashback metacity when dragged from menu to desktop

Tags: unity, gnome, 18.04, nautilus, .desktop

I just installed a fresh 18.04 and use flashback metacity. Up until now everything is working fine ... yet the desktop icons are missing for applications/links added to the desktop. See picture. How can I get/render them?

[image]

Edit: Accept as trustworthy when double click on icon solved it. Steps reproduced:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with missing icons. My solution was to run the Tweaks programm. Under "Appearance" the is an option for "Icons". Choose different icon options until all icons appear again. In my case, choosing "Ubuntu-mono-dark" brought all icons back.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue on clean installation of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with GNOME Shell (default Ubuntu session), GNOME FlashBack (Metacity) and Unity sessions.

This happens even if have enabled desktop icons with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

I have tried to add icons by dragging them from *Applications* menu (in GNOME FlashBack session) to the desktop.

Also I tried to copy them from `/usr/share/applications` (in any session) to Desktop with:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/*gedit.desktop ~/Desktop
chmod +x ~/Desktop/*gedit.desktop
```

Visually the problem looks as following:

you have wrong icon ([[image: wrong Gedit icon[1]]) instead of correct one ([image: correct Gedit icon]).

The **solution** is a double click on the icon and confirm its first launch by clicking on *Trust and Launch*:

[image: user should confirm launching the application]

The method is suitable for all GNOME-based sessions.

Comment: I have icons in 18.04, but not in 19.04. I think this is what I ran. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true`

Comment: @oldfred thanks, but this does not help. I have this option enabled, and still do not have correct icons for applications.

Comment: So what solved it was to double click on each icon and accept the security warning 'Trust and launch'. See above. Not sure if it's supposed to be like that ... but for right now its fine for me.

Comment: Updated my answer to be more clear and useful.